# Refreshing .load section of webpage

Tags: list, refresh, jobs

So I've started working as dispatcher in a company and we have to search jobs for our drivers in US. We are using multiple pages on several screens to "catch" new job ASAP. There's one particular webpage (https://transport-new.acvauctions.com/) which has button for refreshing job list. We're using auto-clickers to click on this button, but it means we can't use cursor elsewhere at that time.

Is there a way to update job list using scripts or something, without a need of a cursor and without refreshing page?

I have tried using Tampermonkey extension, but couldn't script it myself :(